# Background Processes in an Operating System

Tags: process, operating-system

Its a general question , though I searched about it but couldn't match to an exact satisfactory answer ! 
An os runs many processes at a time and for switching of a process it uses the concept of time factor . 
My question is that whenever a process is ran and switched to another process the previous process is halted at that time . Then when we are running a media file(say some audio file) and minimize it ,, how it remains playing ??

Answer (score 1):

It's like Human visual persistence is about 1/16 of a second under normal lighting conditions.

Same way the "time factor" which is used by processor to schedule the process is minute so that user does not feel the difference.